# VBA FindNext does not find all occurrences

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with the function findNext in VBA on Excel.

I have two tabs, "Tab A" and "Tab B". In my first tab, I have all different elements in a column (Banana, apple, pear etc...) and the idea for me is to count the number of times it appeared in the second tab. For example: I know that banana appears 150 times in the second tab.

I used the following function:

```
Function Test()
    Conf = "Banana"
    Dim rgFound As Range
    CptTtl = 0
    With Worksheets("Tab B").Range("L2:L500")
        Set rgFound = .Find(Conf)
        If Not rgFound Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = rgFound.Address
            CptTtl = CptTtl + 1
            Do
                Set rgFound = .FindNext(rgFound)
                CptTtl = CptTtl + 1
            Loop While Not rgFound Is Nothing And rgFound.Address <> firstAddress
            CptTtl = CptTtl - 1
        End If
    End With
    MsgBox CptTtl
End Function
```

So, like I just explained above, when I filter manually, I find 150 bananas, but when I use this function, I find only 118 and I have no idea why.

Does anyone have any ideas?

---

I finally found the solution, here is the solution:

It was just to add this `LookIn:=xlValues`, because I was using formulas and I wanted to look for the value

```
Function Test()
    Conf = "Banana"
    Dim rgFound As Range
    CptTtl = 0
    With Worksheets("Tab B").Range("L2:L500")
        Set rgFound = .Find(Conf, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not rgFound Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = rgFound.Address
            CptTtl = CptTtl + 1
            Do
                Set rgFound = .FindNext(rgFound)
                CptTtl = CptTtl + 1
            Loop While Not rgFound Is Nothing And rgFound.Address <> firstAddress
            CptTtl = CptTtl - 1
        End If
    End With
    MsgBox CptTtl
End Function
```

Comment: Are there any blank rows in your range and are you sure each `Banana` entry is spelt the same with no trailing or preceding spaces?

Comment: there is no blank rows

Comment: `Set rgFound = .Find(Conf)` Use the complete parameters. For example `.Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)`

Comment: @Y.op why don't you use a `CountIf`? that would do it.

Comment: I think your problem may be trailing spaces. I've just tested. Replace `Set rgFound = .Find(Conf)` with `Set rgFound = .Find(Trim(Conf))`

Comment: agree with @nick. Try the code with both `LookAt:=xlPart` and `LookAt:=xlWhole`. If there are any leading of trailing spaces then `xlWhole` will not find them.

Comment: I just checked again, but there's no trailing. `xlWhole` is not working, but `xlPart` also does not find all occurrences.
When I debug, when I get to line 318, it goes back to the first occurrence, and again, I have no jump or empty line.

Comment: BTW you have to use `If Not rgFound Is Nothing Then` again after `.FindNext`. See [THIS Section 3](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/05/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/)

Comment: Also what happens when you change `.Range("L2:L500")` to `.Columns(12)`

Comment: Yes, Thx, but it doesn't change my problem. I would also add that the word pear is found in line 400... While the function no longer finds the word banana from line 318 (while it is still present 50 times)

Comment: Can i see your excel file?

Comment: I just found the problem... I had to add this : `.Find(Conf, LookIn:=xlValues)`. Thx for the help guys!

Comment: I did suggest using `LookIn:=` :D Also pointed towards a link above which show how to use it :)

Comment: Yes, but I didn't pay attention to the LookIn parameter, and I forgot that I was using formulas in some places... Thank you! ^^